# GeoLocation API for pre-determined locations

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

Assignment for college that is giving me a hell of a headache.  Essentially: a drop-down menu that lists three famous places. When the user selects a place from the drop-down menu, show the Google Maps™ entry for that location.

So I already created a site, I have the map loaded to lat/lan through the java coding but can't get the other part (the three famous places) bit to work (actually I can't even figure out how).  Here's what I got so far.

text

```
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td width= "10%">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <select id = "sites">
                            <option value = "utt">UTT</option>
                            <option value = "CSB">CSB</option>
                            <option value = "TCB">TCB</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td width="90%">
                    <div id="googleMap" style="width:150%;height:500px;"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        <script>
            function myMap() {
                var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng();
                    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("googleMap");
                    var mapOptions = {center: myCenter, zoom: 5};
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:myCenter});
                    marker.setMap(map);
            }
        </script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey(haverealoneinactual)&callback=myMap"></script>
    </body>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been racking my brain for days on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example on how I solved it (add your api key): http://jsbin.com/jazijig/1/edit?html,css,js,output

I don't know how far you need to go with this project, but for what you ask as simple as loading a new map with the coordinates of each place every time your dropdown change will do.

```
var Drop = document.getElementById("wonders");

Drop.addEventListener("change", loadMap);

function loadMap() {
if (Drop.value == "University_of_Texas_Tower") {

    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(30.2861584, -97.7415588);
    console.log(Drop.value);
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("googleMap");
    var mapOptions = {
        center: myCenter,
        zoom: 14
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myCenter
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
} else if (Drop.value == "Congress_Street_Bridge") {
    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(30.2718051, -97.7436219);
    console.log(Drop.value);
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("googleMap");
    var mapOptions = {
        center: myCenter,
        zoom: 14
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myCenter
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
} else {
    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(30.2746698, -97.7425392);
    console.log(Drop.value);
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("googleMap");
    var mapOptions = {
        center: myCenter,
        zoom: 14
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myCenter
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
}
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  That did it, thank you very much.  I figured it would be variable based with if/else statements but I couldn't for the life of me figure out the how of it.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using a google maps,So there are lot of supports API's to solve this issue, As this is very common issue which developer faces in their early stages.

For your problem I recommend to store the place Id you like to show in drop-down and then use google API's to show the entry for that location when user select any of them .
you can refer below code:

```
function initialize() {
  // Create a map centered in Pyrmont, Sydney (Australia).
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -33.8666, lng: 151.1958},
    zoom: 15
  });

  // Search for Google's office in Australia.
  var request = {
    location: map.getCenter(),
    radius: '500',
    query: 'Google Sydney'
  };

  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.textSearch(request, callback);
}

// Checks that the PlacesServiceStatus is OK, and adds a marker
// using the place ID and location from the PlacesService.
function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      place: {
        placeId: results[0].place_id,
        location: results[0].geometry.location
      }
    });
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Reference : https://developers.google.com/places/place-id

and if you like to knew about three famous location in particular radius(nearby) you can use :

```
var map;
var service;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
  var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: pyrmont,
      zoom: 15
    });

  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: '500',
    type: ['restaurant']
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Refs : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places